# Add a bottom line at the end of loop group in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

Shadow Wizard help me showing this code to me:

```
<%
Set oRS= TarefasConexaoMSSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM apptabela ORDER BY oito ASC")
Dim currentGroupName, previousGroupName
currentGroupName = ""
previousGroupName = ""
Do Until oRS.EOF
    currentGroupName = oRS("oito")
    One = oRS("um")
    Two = oRS("dois")
    If currentGroupName<>previousGroupName Then
        Response.Write("<p>")
        Response.Write("<a href='#'>" & currentGroupName & "</a>")
        Response.Write("</p>")
    End If
    Response.Write("- One: " & One & ", Two: " & Two & "<br />")
    previousGroupName = currentGroupName
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
%>
```

it's generating something like:

> 1000
>
> - One: Apples, Two: Pear
> - One: Volks, Two: Lexus
>
> 1001
>
> - One: Car, Two: Boat
>
> 1002
>
> - One: Chicken, Two: Cow
> - One: Pen, Two: Pencil
> - One: C#, Two: C++

What I want is to add a line at the bottom of the each group, like a Sum, so later I can do some calculations:

> 1000
>
> - One: Apples, Two: Pear
> - One: Volks, Two: Lexus
> - SUM: X, Y
>
> 1001
>
> - One: Car, Two: Boat
> - SUM: X, Y
>
> 1002
>
> - One: Chicken, Two: Cow
> - One: Pen, Two: Pencil
> - One: C#, Two: C++
> - SUM: X, Y

Thanks

Comment: so how you wanna add apples to pears again ;)) I assume you have numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

you can use this jquery plugin for your requirement. If you can not understand how to implement then please let me know. I have used this recently.

Comment: Thanks but JQuery isn't necessary in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
Set oRS= TarefasConexaoMSSQL.Execute("SELECT * FROM apptabela ORDER BY oito ASC")
Dim currentGroupName, previousGroupName, sumone, sumtwo
currentGroupName = ""
previousGroupName = ""
Do Until oRS.EOF
    currentGroupName = oRS("oito")
    One = oRS("um")
    Two = oRS("dois")
    If currentGroupName<>previousGroupName Then
        (!)Response.write("- Sum: " & sumone & ", " & sumtwo)
        (!)sumone = 0 / ""
        (!)sumtwo = sumone
        Response.Write("<p>")
        Response.Write("<a href='#'>" & currentGroupName & "</a>")
        Response.Write("</p>")
    End If
    Response.Write("- One: " & One & ", Two: " & Two & "<br />")
    (!)sumone = sumone + one
    (!)sumtwo = sumtwo + two
    previousGroupName = currentGroupName
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
%>
```

this shoud fix it. as you are ordering by groupname and want a sum for every group you have to sum things up when printing the group elements and print the sum when goint into a new group + clear the sum before summing up again. this should also work if you are using string, but maybe you would want to add whitespaces when summing up then

Comment: dat was a bad example of mine... i will try do a better one...'cause i can't make this to work with this code... thanks